# Error Loading program in emualor (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, emulation

I had accidentally deleted my android.bat and now emulator is running but it is not allowing me to run any program in emulator

```
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redownload the SDK, as a SDK Tools only. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rich This is a good answer, and the link is key to the answer anyway.